# Merging lists by ID using Lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

I was wondering if anyone could help me simplify the following piece of code.

I basically have two lists, I essentially want to check if the item in the second list matches the first by ID. If it does, I want to update the object in the first list with the values of the second.

```
        postPatch.getSections().forEach(patched -> {

        originalSection.getSections().forEach(original -> {

            if (original.getId().equals(patched.getId())) {
                original.setContent(patched.getContent());
                original.setImagePosition(patched.getImagePosition());
                original.setTitle(patched.getTitle());
                original.setImageUrl(patched.getImageUrl());
            }
        });
    });
```

I feel like there is a better way to express this with Java8 but can't quite find what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it correctly. I would make a separate method to update.

Assuming this is the POJO class which you want to update

```
public class Image {
    private Integer id;
    private String content;
    private Cell position;
    private String title;
    private URL imageURL;

    // ...

    public void updateIfMatch(Image patch) {
        if (Objects.equals(id, patch.id)) {
            id = patch.id;
            content = patch.content;
            position = patch.position;
            title = patch.title;
            imageURL = patch.imageURL;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code to update list

```
getPostPatchedSections().forEach(a -> getOriginalSections().forEach(a::updateIfMatch));
```

**Alternate Solution**

You can also do the id comparison in stream instead of doing in Image class. This solution is more Java 8ish

```
public class Image {
    private Integer id;
    private String content;
    private Cell position;
    private String title;
    private URL imageURL;

    // ...

    public void updateFrom(Image patch) {
        id = patch.id;
        content = patch.content;
        position = patch.position;
        title = patch.title;
        imageURL = patch.imageURL;
    }
}
```

Here is the pipeline code to update lists

```
    getPostPatchedSections()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(a -> getOriginalSections()
                    .filter(a::equals)
                    .forEach(a::updateFrom));
```

Comment: Thanks, this was closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you really want to be using a Map so you can lookup player by id.

```
// Map of id to player.
Map<Integer, Player> players = new HashMap<>();

players.putAll(originalMap);

players.putAll(patchMap);
```

All the entries in the patchMap will add or replace those in the players, matched by `id`  This is an `O(n)` operation instead of `O(n^2)`